# JMS appender session error after prolonged inactivity

Tags: log4j2, jboss-eap-7, activemq-artemis

We are using a JMS appender to write to JBoss EAP7 ActiveMQ.   If there is no logging activity for a period of time ( not sure of duration at this point - several hours at least), then get this error:

occurred processing Appender HIFAuditAppender org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AppenderLoggingException: javax.jms.IllegalStateException: Session is closed

Here is the appender config:

```
<JMS name="HIFAuditAppender"
         destinationBindingName="jms/queue/HIFAuditQueue"
         factoryBindingName="jms/RemoteConnectionFactory" 
         providerURL="http-remoting://hsnban-bil01.bannerlab.int:8080"
         username="hcmuser"
         password="gators123="
         immediateFail="false"
         reconnectIntervalMill="60000"
         factoryName="org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory" />
```

I would assume log4j2 would re-try to obtain a new session.

Comment: Are you trying to close of the running connection/session anywhere at some places during the process? if it is then this is not a good idea.

Comment: No.  Actually I found out from log4j support group that JMS retry was only added in version 2.10, and I was using 2.7. So trying to upgrade and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: How is the connection factory "jms/RemoteConnectionFactory" configured on the server?  Do you know why the session is closed?

Comment: Good question.  I will research that.